# C# Dynamic Panel SubPanel-Event Loop bug

Tags: c#, dynamic, panel, flowlayoutpanel

I am currently making an UI using a flow layout panel in visual studio 19.
If i press a button it clones a panel using

```
public static T Clone<T>(this T controlToClone) where T : Control
    {
        PropertyInfo[] controlProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        T instance = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        foreach (PropertyInfo propInfo in controlProperties)
        {
            if (propInfo.CanWrite)
            {
                if (propInfo.Name != "WindowTarget")
                    propInfo.SetValue(instance, propInfo.GetValue(controlToClone, null), null);
            }
        }

        return instance;
    }
```

In the same press event it fires AddNewPanel("name");

```
private void AddPanel(string name)
        {
            var label = new Label();
            label.AutoSize = false;
            label.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            label.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            label.Text = name;
            label.MouseEnter += labelEnter;
            label.MouseLeave += labelLeave;

            var panel = panel1.Clone();
            var button = button1.Clone();
            button.Name = "button" + new Random().Next(1, 100);

            panel.Controls.Add(button);
            panel.Controls.Add(label);

            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(panel);
        }
```

the event labelEnter triggers ShowButtons()

```
private void showButtons()
        {
            foreach (Control item in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls)
            {
                var button = item.Controls[1];
                button.Visible = true;
            }
        }
```

and the mouseLeave event does the same except turning Visible to false.

Now I have experienced, dynamically adding Controls to a panel which then gets added to a flowlayout panel causes some Issues. For example, the labelMouseEnter/Leave event gets looped when moving the mouse over the button. Anyone experienced this before or similiar posts regarding this? It doesn't happen when the button is initially Visible, meaning Visible is turned to true in designer View. It clones it with the visible attribute.

Comment: Throw away the flowlayoutpanel.  I've found too many issues trying to do things beyond the very basics.  I create my own array of child panels which has all the properties of a panel.  The flowlayoutpanel has very few properties.

Comment: "For example, the labelMouseEnter/Leave event gets looped when moving the mouse over the button."  The label is set to Dock filled, so it takes up the entire space of the panel.  Presumably, the button is then smaller than and on top of the label?  If so, then it is normal for the label to get a mouseleave event when you enter the button, because you did in fact leave the label!  If you don't want this to occur then you'll have to write extra code in the mouseleave event  that checks the current mouse position and doesn't treat it as a "leave" if the coords of the label contain the mouse.

Comment: @Idle_Mind yeah thats it. I have tried it before without success, i gave it another try with another logic and it worked.

Comment: Nice!  Glad that steered you in the right direction.

Comment: You could post that as a solution and accept it as the answer.  It might help someone else in the future...

Comment: @Idle_Mindthanks It says I have to wait 2 Days. After that I will do it! Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution is to add a check in the MouseLeave event as following:

```
 private void control_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var control = sender as Control;
            if (control.ClientRectangle.Contains(control.PointToClient(Cursor.Position))) return;
            //rest 
            ShowButtons();
        }
```